# $scope.$on not listening after browser refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular ui-router.
I have the following structure :

- state a controller parentA
- state a.b Controller childB

I have a resolved on state a.b that broadcast event 'event1' and I have a listener on parentA controller.

It works fine when I login. But on subsequent browser refreshes, I can see the event being broadcast but the listener is not working.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Might this code helps you

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', onLoaded);
$scope.$on('viewContentLoadComplete', onLoadComplete);

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
        $scope.isViewLoading = true;
    });

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $scope.isViewLoading = false;
    });

function onLoaded() { 
    $scope.isViewLoading = true;
    $scope.$broadcast('viewContentLoadComplete');
}

function onLoadComplete() { 
    $scope.isViewLoading = false;
}
```

When you traverse between the views be it parent or child you always gonna fall is this condition where you can handle the stuffs you wish.

Better code than this is also welcome with brief explanation.

You can define this in your main controller.Here $scope.isViewLoading is just a gif image which is set to hide and show as loader.